# Android: SQLite no such table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello I am getting a "no such table" error when I want to fill in data in my sqlite db

I am asking myself if the syntax is wrong

```
  private static final String KEY_ID= "blabla";
    private static final String KEY_VALUE1 = "blabla";
    private static final String KEY_VALUE2 = "blabla";
    private static final String KEY_VALUE3= "blabla";
    private static final String KEY_VALUE4= "blabla";
```

....

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXAMPLETABLE 
            + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + KEY_VALUE1 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_VALUE2 + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_VALUE3 + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_VALUE4 + " TEXT " 
            + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}
```

do you see any mistake?

Comment: Too little code. Please add more.

Comment: Post a complete stack trace from logcat

Comment: Post the complete class....